# How can I speed up my integration program in python?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science, integral

I made a simple GUI for solving user inputed integrals and I was wondering if there would be any way to speed up the process of taking integrals in my code without sacrificing accuracy? It is pretty quick for small ranges but when the lower and upper bounds get larger it becomes very inefficient.

```
from tkinter import *
import parser
from math import *

def Integrate(eq, a, b):
    code = parser.expr(eq).compile() #parses user string into equation
    dx = 0.0000001
    area = 0.0
    x = a
    x_f = b
    while x <= x_f:
        x += dx
        area += (dx*eval(code))
    answer = float("{0:.5f}".format(area))
    print(answer)

master = Tk()
master.title("Integration Program")

instruction = Label(master, text="Enter f(x): ")
instruction.grid(row=0, column=0)

lower_label = Label(master, text="Lower Bound: ")
lower_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

upper_label = Label(master, text="Upper Bound: ")
upper_label.grid(row=0, column=2)

f_of_x = StringVar()
lwr = StringVar()
upr = StringVar()

entry_f = Entry(master, textvariable=f_of_x, width=20)
entry_f.grid(row=1, column=0)

entry_l = Entry(master, textvariable=lwr, width=5)
entry_l.grid(row=1, column=1)

entry_u = Entry(master, textvariable=upr, width=5)
entry_u.grid(row=1, column=2)

go = Button (master, text = "Integrate",
             command= lambda: Integrate(f_of_x.get(),
                                    float(lwr.get()), 
float(upr.get())))
go.grid(row=2, column=1)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use higher order integration methods e.g. Simpson's method or Runge-Kutta which will let you use a larger `dx`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by c2huc2hu in the comments, you can use a different method of numerical integration. Whole books on numerical analysis have been written to describe different options and which is most appropriate in any given situation.

Another option worth considering - and which is frequently considered when researchers really want to solve large computational problems - is parallelization. Euler's method, which appears to be essentially what you are doing (basically using a finite Riemann sum to approximate the definite integral) is ridiculously parallel: you can break the range [a, b] into as many subranges as you want and have a separate processor solve each one. Now, if you are running on a single CPU core, this buys you nothing and adds overhead. However, if you have a multicore CPU - I imagine all CPUs have multiple cores now - you can get close to a directly proportional speedup for this kind of computation by using all available parallel pipelines.

Now consider having something like a GPU, where you can use hundreds of cores. You could write the above integration in CUDA and a PC with a run-of-the-mill NVIDIA graphics card could chew through your problems hundreds of times faster than a single-threaded CPU application could. All of this with no - or, if you use single-point on the GPU, possibly still tolerable - loss of accuracy. What would parallel code for this look like?

```
dx = <const>
xi = <const>
xf = <const>

pt = floor((xf - xi) / dx)

tc = <const>
tl = ()

for n = 1 to tc do
    pt_start = floor(pt / tc) * (n - 1) + 1
    pt_stop = floor(pt / tc) * n
    x_start = xi + (pt_start - 1) * dx
    x_stop = xi + (pt_stop - 1) * dx
    if n = tc then x_stop = xf
    tl.add(new job(x_start, x_stop))

for n = 1 to tc do
    tl(n).start()

for n = 1 to tc do
    tl(n).join()

sum = 0
for n = 1 to tc do
    sum = sum + tl(n).result

return result
```

Note that the `job` function being run in parallel in the background just needs to integrate the function from `x_start` to `x_stop` using your method exactly as written.